# How to Auto Call My Method In Time Period Without Running any WebPage in my application in ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-pool, preload, autostart

I Want to Automatically Run my Method in evry for example 10 minute.
But i Do not want to Run Any Page to Do it.
I Want to Click on a button and then EVEN IF I CLOSE MY PAGE the application Do the method evry 10 minute.
For Example :

```
 protected void AutoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//I want to application run above methods evry 10 minute EVEN IF I CLOSE THE PAGE
        GetGoldPrices();
        SaveGoldPrices();
        GetCoinPrices();
        SaveCoinPrices();
        GetExchangePrices();
        SaveExchangePrices();
    }
```

I Found This [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) which was useful but i get my host from a company and can not set any thing out of my WEB SITE PANEL...
Any suggest to how can i do this please?

Comment: This is not what web applications are for. You should look into creating a Windows Service instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6507/NET-Scheduled-Timer

Its a nice package for scheduling repeating functions.

You would have to set up a timer at the top level of your program if you want it to run even when the pages are closed.

Comment: Your welcome i ran into a similar problem with an MVC4 project a while back, its not strictly in the spirit of web applications but it works : )